# How to convert NSString path to CFURLRef (for iOS 3.1)?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurl, nsbundle, cfstring

I display a PDF in a UIScrollView. To do so I use:

```
myDocumentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"salonMap" withExtension:@"pdf"]);
```

Now, I try to make it work on an IOS 3.1 (NSBundle URLForResource:withExtension does not exist for 3.1)

I turned my code into:

```
NSString *fullPath =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"salonMap" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSLog(@"%@", fullPath);
CFStringRef fullPathEscaped = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)fullPath, NULL, NULL,kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFURLRef urlRef = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL, fullPathEscaped, NULL);
myDocumentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(urlRef);
```

But it leads to a

```
<Error>: CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource: failed with error code -15
```

I precise that NSLog logs

```
/var/mobile/Applications/1CF69390-85C7-45DA-8981-A279464E3249/myapp.app/salonMap.pdf"
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSURL is [interchangeable](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html) with CFURLRef thanks to toll-free bridging.  Try this:

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                     pathForResource:@"salonMap" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's important to mention that this will no longer work if you are using ARC. As a result you will need to create a bridged cast. See below:

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                 pathForResource:@"salonMap" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
```